# Adapting Python Code to Extract Mentions from Tweets for Mention Network

Tags: python, json, twitter

**Background:**

I found this code from Alex Hanna (https://github.com/alexhanna) and I've been trying to adapt it to my situation, but haven't been as successful as I would like, and was hoping for help.

This code takes JSON output from the Twitter API and extracts user mentions from it to create a mention network.  Currently, the code is executed as follows:

```
cat file.json | mentionMapper.py
```

**Desires:**

I would like to change it so that the python code reads in the JSON file. Previously I've used the code below, but haven't been able to figure out how to adapt it for this instance.

```
for line in in_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
    except:
        pass
```

I would also like the code to write the output to a CSV file instead of printing it to the screen or having to manually direct the output using > after the code.

**Ultimate Goal:**

Edgelist of Twitter users who mention one another.

**Code:**

```
import json
import sys

def main():

    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()

        data = ''
        try:
            data = json.loads(line)
        except ValueError as detail:
            continue

        if not (isinstance(data, dict)):
            ## not a dictionary, skip
            pass
        elif 'delete' in data:
            ## a delete element, skip for now.
            pass
        elif 'user' not in data:
            ## bizarre userless edge case
            pass
        else:
            if 'entities' in data and len(data['entities']['user_mentions']) > 0:
                user = data['user']
                user_mentions = data['entities']['user_mentions']

                for u2 in user_mentions:
                    print ",".join([
                        user['screen_name'],
                        u2['screen_name'],
                        "1"
                        ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Okay, ignoring the specific functionality of the file, your issue is with how to interact with the file? Am I off-base there?

Comment: @Zeroth Yes, I want to read-in my file, process it using the above code, and write-out the results to a CSV.  With another code, I used `sys.argv` to specify the input file name, and would like to do that here as well.  But I can't figure out how to read-in the file, as opposed to just piping file like it's currently configured.

Comment: You are reading in the file - sys.stdin is a buffer, which is how  files behave in Python, as buffers. They are functionally the same.

Comment: Are you wanting to use command-line arguments for your code? Check this out then: http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

Comment: @Zeroth I see what you're saying.  Yes, I would like to use pass the input file name to the code through the command line.  From the link you shared, I think I see how I can do that. What about writing the output to a CSV file?  What could I use that would be more concise than using `.py > newfile.csv` ?

Comment: You could either pass in another file name to write to, if you want. 

You seem to misunderstand the use of conciseness. The example you gave is very concise in that its small, and obvious what it does. But fewer characters is not always the best. You can't get much smaller than that example without hard-coded filenames.

Comment: Thanks @Zeroth! I understand being concise, and appreciate it. I'm just new to this and trying to make it ass comprehensive as possible, so it's quick and easy for anyone to use. If you think it's best as is, I'll leave it that way and continue to use it like it was written. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Well, there's multiple ways to do the output. For example, you can internally attach stdout to a file instead of a buffer, and suddenly, you're writing to a file anytime you do a print command. 

Because there's a bunch of different ways to work with files, you either choose a paradigm you like, the one favored by your platform(windows vs unix style for ex.), or you provide the flexibility to do all of them through command line arguments. 

Its all up to you, each with pros and cons. You have to decide what matters to *you* and your users.

Comment: You can pass in a filename via command line, print to stdout allowing for piping(unix style), redirect stdout to a file either based on defaults or a filename passed in, write to a file that is the input file name + "_out" or whatever. So many ways to go here. 

Flexibility can cost conciseness, while conciseness cuts down on flexibility.